# Could "essentia" be understood in Latin as "the act of being"?

Tags: verbs, noun

Almost every verb has a noun that implies "the act and effect of" whatever the verb is. So, an *existence* is the act of *existing*. Nonetheless, the most simple verb, *to be* seems to lack such a noun, at least [in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28280/12637) (link in Spanish, sorry).

But then someone came up with *essence* as a possibility for the noun of *to be*, but in Spanish it lacks that meaning (it means roughly "the most important and charasteristic part of a thing"). But what about Latin? In Latin we have *exsistĕre* and its noun *exsistentia*, and also *[essentĭa](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DE%3Aentry%20group%3D25%3Aentry%3Dessentia)* which seems to mean *the being* or *essence* of a thing, according to the Lewis & Short dictionary.

Can then *essentĭa* be understood as "the act of being" the same way as *exsistentia* is "the act of existing"?

Answer (score 8):

No. *Essentia* (to-be-ness) was coined by Cicero as a Latin counterpart for the Greek οὐσία (ousia). Both words refer to something's essence or nature, that which makes a thing "to be" the particular kind of thing that it is. Nature or essence is contrasted with accidents, those qualities of a thing that can change without changing what kind of thing something is.

Eventually, medieval philosophers would come up with three terms: *ens* (an existing thing), *essentia* (the nature of a thing), and *esse* (the act or property of being/existing). So, every thing that actually exists (*ens*) possesses both a particular nature (*essentia*) and the property of existing (*esse*).

Comment: So the word I am looking for is "esse"?

Comment: @Charlie yes, esse.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, *the act of being* in Medieval philosophy was called **actus essendi** (from which the English and Spanish expressions are mere translations). [The term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actus_Essendi) was apparently coined by St. Thomas Aquinas (XIII cent.)

Answer (score 1):

The original meaning of οὐσία is “that which is one’s own; property”, attested since Herodotus. In the philosophers (Plato, Aristotle and perhaps already Democritus) it takes on the sense “true nature of something” as opposed to πάθη. Latin essentia is a calque on οὐσία and is not attested before the imperial period, though Seneca says that he thinks it was coined by Cicero ("Ciceronem auctorem hujus verbi habeo").

Answer (score 0):

Well I agree with Kingshorsey about *Essentia.* If I talked about Unicorns, or Justice, or Beauty, you know what I mean because you know their essence: *essentia.*

And if I asked you to describe them you might start with 'spiral horns and white hair;' or 'wigs, black robes, and juries;' or 'angel choirs and tangerine skies.' These are 
accidental properties which remind you of the 'Essentia.'

But in this world Unicorns are not alive; Justice turns out to be about plea bargaining and how much you can afford for a lawyer; and beauty means hours of sweat in a gym or sleepless nights creating a novel.

What Unicorns don't have; but what Law, and ballet, and novels have is an extra something called 'ΥΛΗ

I think the word you are looking for is 'ΥΛΗ or hyle. Accusative hylen.

But I'm just an apocalyptic platonist.

Comment: I think most ancient and medieval philosophers would disagree: matter (hyle) isn't a principle of existence. Immaterial substances can fail to exist just as much as material substances.

Comment: @brianpck While it's abstract nature, and the accidental nature have been discussed, I thought Charlie was asking for the actuality, the 'thing,' the kickable object and its distinctive reality in the world. Isn't that hyle?